# create dataframe in pandas, why the creation leads to the clear of the zip of tuples?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
sentences=['aaa','bbb','ccc']
labels = [1,2,3]
infos = zip(sentences , labels)
df_synthesize = pd.DataFrame(infos, columns = ['content','label'])
print(df_synthesize)
print(list(infos))
```

I use the `infos` to initialize the dataframe, however, after the creation, the infos becomes null list.

```
print(list(infos))
```

[]

It is quite weird, why this happens?

pandas version : `1.1.5`

Comment: hi friend. this is not your style?

Comment: do you want dataframe or method of using zip

Comment: why is my answer minus

Comment: you'd rather say thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. `panddas`: `1.1.5`

```
import pandas as pd
sentences=['aaa','bbb','ccc']
labels = [1,2,3]
infos = list(zip(sentences , labels))
       // ^----------------------------------- clue
df_synthesize = pd.DataFrame(infos, columns = ['content','label'])
print(df_synthesize)
```

Output

```
  content  label
0     aaa      1
1     bbb      2
2     ccc      3
```